# Slide Menu Layout returns null reference for left and content view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to get the reference of SlideMenuLayout left and content view , but when I called `getSlideLeftView()` it returns null !

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RootActivity">


<com.jkb.slidemenu.SlideMenuLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainSlideMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:slideMode="left">
    <include layout="@layout/left_menu_layout" />
    <include layout="@layout/content_layout" />
</com.jkb.slidemenu.SlideMenuLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Root Activity :

```
public class RootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SlideMenuLayout leftMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);

        leftMenu = (SlideMenuLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainSlideMenu);

        View left = leftMenu.getSlideLeftView(); // returns null !!!

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, DashboardFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [SlideMenuLayout](https://github.com/JingYeoh/SlideMenuLayout) source code, I see that left slide menu view, right slide menu view, content view only initialized inside `onMeasure()` method, so you need to change your code to:

```
leftMenu.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                               int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        leftMenu.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

        // Initialize left, right, content view here
        View leftView = leftMenu.getSlideLeftView(); 
    }
});
```